# Dataprep - Dataflow fails when output is BigQuery

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataprep

As a part of the POC I was trying to setup some data quality checks through Dataprep.
There is a BigQuery table as a source and it should run a job with output to another BigQuery.
Unfortunately that job fails with error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create job with prefix beam_load_[thenameofthejob], reached max retries: 3, last failed job: null.
   at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryHelpers$PendingJob.runJob(BigQueryHelpers.java:196)
   at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryHelpers$PendingJobManager.waitForDone(BigQueryHelpers.java:149)
   at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteTables$WriteTablesDoFn.finishBundle(WriteTables.java:255) .
```

Do you have any hints how to solve this, please?

I have edited recipes and did not setup any transformation there just to see if the job runs - it failed again.
It works when I output this dataprep dataflow into csv. 
It is all running in EU region.

Comment: Were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

try to go to the bigquery page and then go to task history.
the flollowing step is to go to the tab project history inside task history.
there you will find the red exclemation mark at the failed attempt.
if you click on that case, you will see the specific error message for that case.

in my case it was the locations that were different, but yours were fine so this is as far as i can help i guess.
hope it will help you.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer but this is the error from the task history. java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create job with prefix beam_load_[thenameofthejob], reached max retries: 3, last failed job: null.
   at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryHelpers$PendingJob.runJob(BigQueryHelpers.java:196)
   at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.BigQueryHelpers$PendingJobManager.waitForDone(BigQueryHelpers.java:149)
   at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteTables$WriteTablesDoFn.finishBundle(WriteTables.java:255) .